# Set the default value of a dropdown which is populated dynamically using Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I see a lot of dropdowns defined at multiple locations in my JSP. something like this: (with different Ids).

```
 <select class="school-names" name="schoolName" id="AASchoolName" >     </select>
```

These dropdowns are populated as below:

```
 <c:forEach items="${schools}" var="sc">
    var scName = "${sc.schoolName}";
     jQuery('.school-names').append('<option value="' + scName + '">' + scName +   '</option>');
 </c:forEach>
```

This dropdown is populated on load of the JSP page. How to set the default value of each dropdown onload of this JSP page.

Comment: `defaultselected` property? or set `selected`?

Comment: The selected value of a dropdown in each section will depend on some other value of each section. Eg., I got 3 dropdowns with ids a1,a2,a3. The dropdown values are RED, GREEN, YELLOW. i would need RED as selected value for a1, GREEN-a2 and YELLOW-a3 dropdowns. I tried using  " <option value="0" selected="selected">RED</option>" . But this adds a new option in dropdowns. Could you throw an idea please?

Comment: i found the solution: This needs a jquery function which i have written in java script "on Ready " function.  I used Jquery.each operation so that i can loop over each section and set the value for that particular dropdown. jQuery(selector).val(default.value);